# Parse complex date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, date-parsing

I have a date in string, provide by webservices:

```
2013-05-13T10:06:34.023-03:00
```

How to parse this to Java Date?

**SimpleDateFormat** with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` doesn't work...

I need only date and time (not -3:00).

Thanks, 
Mateus

Comment: Sorry, but RTFM. The javadoc for SimpleDateFormat contains an example for exactly that format.

Comment: google it @david99world :)

Answer (score 2):

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` does not work because it does not match your example.

What about `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"`?

I took this pattern from JavaDoc of `SimpleDateFormat`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to use:

`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` as per the JavaDoc for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

I would also suggest you do need the `-3:00` - this is the timezone the time applies to and says the time is UTC -3 hours.